# Java FTPClient for Mainframe GDG

Tags: ftp-client

I'm trying to transfer file to Mainframe using Java FTPClient.Below code works for normal datasets in mainframe. But when i try to transfer file to mainframe GDG (Generation Data Groups) like 'FTPAA.TEST.BBBB.DLY(+1)'. Its not working. Is there any specific settings need to do in FTPClient to transfer file to GDG or am i missing any configurations?

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException;

......
File file = new File("abc.csv");
String testName = "FTPAA.TEST";
fis = new FileInputStream(file);

// Upload file to the ftp server
try{
result = ftpclient.storeFile(testName, fis);
}
```